# Analysis with Parallel Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, analysis, bubble-sort

Everyone knows that `bubblesort` is `O(n^2)`, but this is based on the number of comparisons needed to sort this. I have a question in which, if I didn't care about the number of comparisons, but the output time, then how do you do analysis of this? Is there a way to do analysis on output time instead of comparisons?

For example, if you could have bubble sort and have parallel comparisons happening at for all pairs (even then odd comparisons), then the throughput time would be something like `2n-1` throughput time. The number of comparisons would be high, but I don't care as the final throughput time is quick.

So in essence, is there a common analysis for overall parallel performance time? If so, just give me some key terms and I'll learn the rest from google.

Comment: One of my old professors replied to me in email about looking for `round complexity` for such cases. I'm trying to see if I can find a reference and verify its use.

Comment: `Round` in the sense of parallel steps happening at the same time. Makes sense.

Comment: This sounds similar to something that, in the book "Introduction to Algorithms", is called span. It's defined as the running time of an algorithm on an infinite number of processors.

Answer (score 2):

Parallel programming is a bit of red herring here.  **Making assumptions about run time only on big O notation can be misleading. To compare run times of algorithms you need the full equation not just the big O notation.**

The problem is that big O notation tells you the dominating term as `n` goes to infinity. But the run time is on finite ranges of `n`. This is easy to understand from continuous mathematics (my background).

Consider `y=Ax` and `y=Bx^2`  Big O notation would tell you that `y=Bx^2` is slower.  However, between (0,A/B) it's less than `y=Ax`.  In this case it could be faster to use the O(x^2) algorithm than the O(x) algorithm for `x<A/B`.

In fact I have heard of sorting algorithms which start off with a O(nlogn) algorithm and then switch to a O(n^2) logarithm when n is sufficiently small.

The best example is matrix multiplication.  The naïve algorithm is O(n^3) but there are algorithms that get that down to O(n^2.3727).  However, every algorithm I have seen has such a large constant that the naïve O(n^3) is still the fastest algorithm for all particle values of `n` and that does not look likely to change any time soon.

So really what you need is the full equation to compare.  Something like `An^3` (let's ignore lower order terms) and `Bn^2.3727`.  In this case B is so incredibly large that the O(n^3) method always wins.

Parallel programming usually just lowers the constant.  For example when I do matrix multiplication using four cores my time goes from `An^3` to `A/4 n^3`.  The same thing will happen with your parallel bubble sort.  You will decrease the constant.  So it's possible that for some range of values of `n` that your parallel bubble sort will beat a non-parallel (or possibly even parallel) merge sort.  Though, unlike matrix multiplication, I think the range will be pretty small.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm analysis is not meant to give actual run times. That's what benchmarks are for. Analysis tells you how much relative complexity is in a program, but the actual run time for that program depends on so many other factors that strict analysis can't guarantee real-world times. For example, what happens if your OS decides to suspend your program to install updates? Your run time will be shot. Even running the same program over and over yields different results due to the complexity of computer systems (memory page faults, virtual machine garbage collection, IO interrupts, etc). Analysis can't take these into account.

This is why parallel processing doesn't usually come under consideration during analysis. The mechanism for "parallelizing" a program's components is usually external to your code, and usually based on a probabilistic algorithm for scheduling. I don't know of a good way to do static analysis on that. Once again, you can run a bunch of benchmarks and that will give you an average run time.

Answer (score 0):

The time efficiency we get by parallel steps can be measured by `round complexity`. Where each round consists of parallel steps occurring at the same time. By doing so, we can see how effective the throughput time is, in similar analysis that we are used to.

Comment: Do you have any additional information on this? I think it's interesting, but I've never heard of it before.

Comment: Look into distributed computing. I think Nancy Lynch, a professor at MIT, has a good book. The general concept is for similar speed processors, or based on the slowest in the group, allowing each processor to make at least one step in the algorithm.